# Spring unit testing java-config maven Failed to load ApplicationContext

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, applicationcontext

i am trying to test my application with spring test, but after a lot of tries of config, i'm asking for help!

my config files:

appConfig:

```
@Configuration
@Profile(value="profile1")
@ComponentScan(basePackages={"br.uem.gestaoresiduos"},
    excludeFilters=@ComponentScan.Filter(type=FilterType.REGEX, pattern={"br.uem.gestaoresiduos.web.*"}))
@PropertySource(value = { "classpath:application.properties" })
@EnableScheduling
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
@EnableCaching
public class AppConfig{
    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    @Bean
    public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer placeHolderConfigurer()
    {
        return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
    }

    @Bean
    public JavaMailSenderImpl javaMailSenderImpl() {
        JavaMailSenderImpl mailSenderImpl = new JavaMailSenderImpl();
        mailSenderImpl.setHost(env.getProperty("smtp.host"));
        mailSenderImpl.setPort(env.getProperty("smtp.port", Integer.class));
        mailSenderImpl.setProtocol(env.getProperty("smtp.protocol"));
        mailSenderImpl.setUsername(env.getProperty("smtp.username"));
        mailSenderImpl.setPassword(env.getProperty("smtp.password"));

        Properties javaMailProps = new Properties();
        javaMailProps.put("mail.smtp.auth", true);
        javaMailProps.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", true);

        mailSenderImpl.setJavaMailProperties(javaMailProps);

        return mailSenderImpl;
    }

    @Bean
    public CacheManager cacheManager()
    {
        return new ConcurrentMapCacheManager();
    }
}
```

PersistenceConfig.java

```
@Configuration  
@EnableTransactionManagement
    @EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages="br.uem.gestaoresiduos.repositories")
@PropertySource(value = { "classpath:application.properties" })
public class PersistenceConfig 
{
@Autowired
private Environment env;

@Value("${init-db:false}")
private String initDatabase;

@Bean
public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager()
{
    EntityManagerFactory factory = entityManagerFactory().getObject();
    return new JpaTransactionManager(factory);
}

@Bean
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory()
{
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factory = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();

    HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
    vendorAdapter.setGenerateDdl(Boolean.TRUE);
    vendorAdapter.setShowSql(Boolean.TRUE);

    factory.setDataSource(dataSource());
    factory.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
    factory.setPackagesToScan("br.uem.gestaoresiduos.entities");

    Properties jpaProperties = new Properties();
    jpaProperties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", env.getProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto"));
    factory.setJpaProperties(jpaProperties);

    factory.afterPropertiesSet();
    factory.setLoadTimeWeaver(new InstrumentationLoadTimeWeaver());
    return factory;
}

@Bean
public HibernateExceptionTranslator hibernateExceptionTranslator()
{
    return new HibernateExceptionTranslator();
}

@Bean
public DataSource dataSource()
{
    BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();
    dataSource.setDriverClassName(env.getProperty("jdbc.driverClassName"));
    dataSource.setUrl(env.getProperty("jdbc.url"));
    dataSource.setUsername(env.getProperty("jdbc.username"));
    dataSource.setPassword(env.getProperty("jdbc.password"));
    return dataSource;
}

@Bean
public DataSourceInitializer dataSourceInitializer(DataSource dataSource) 
{
    DataSourceInitializer dataSourceInitializer = new DataSourceInitializer();
    dataSourceInitializer.setDataSource(dataSource);
    ResourceDatabasePopulator databasePopulator = new ResourceDatabasePopulator();
    databasePopulator.addScript(new ClassPathResource("db.sql"));
    dataSourceInitializer.setDatabasePopulator(databasePopulator);
    dataSourceInitializer.setEnabled(Boolean.parseBoolean(initDatabase));
    return dataSourceInitializer;
}
```

}

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>br.uem</groupId>
<artifactId>tcc-gestao-residuos</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <junit.version>4.11</junit.version>
    <slf4j.version>1.7.5</slf4j.version>
    <logback.version>1.0.13</logback.version>
    <spring.version>4.2.0.RELEASE</spring.version>
    <spring-data-jpa.version>1.8.2.RELEASE</spring-data-jpa.version>
    <spring-security.version>3.2.0.RELEASE</spring-security.version>
    <hibernate.version>5.0.0.CR4</hibernate.version>
    <aspectj.version>1.7.2</aspectj.version>
    <mysql.version>5.1.26</mysql.version>
    <jackson-json.version>2.3.1</jackson-json.version>
    <commons-dbcp.version>1.2.2</commons-dbcp.version>
    <commons-lang3.version>3.1</commons-lang3.version>
    <my.tomcat.path>/root/workspace/tcc-gestao-residuos/target/tomcat</my.tomcat.path>
</properties>

<build>
    <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>${java.version}</source>
                <target>${java.version}</target>
                <webXml>\src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\web.xml</webXml>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <port>8080</port>
                <contextReloadable>true</contextReloadable>
                <outputDirectory>${my.tomcat.path}</outputDirectory>
            </configuration>

        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<dependencies>

    <!-- Logging dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
        <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
        <version>${logback.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spring dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spring Data JPA dependencies -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-data-jpa.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- SpringSecurity dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-security.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-security.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-security.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-security.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
        <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
        <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Testing dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>${junit.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- DB dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>${mysql.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
        <version>${commons-dbcp.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>${jackson-json.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
        <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Web dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>taglibs</groupId>
        <artifactId>standard</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.2</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jstl</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-framework-bom</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

User.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name="users")
public class User 
{
    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;
    private String name;
    @Column(nullable=false, unique=true)
    private String email;
    @Column(nullable=false)
    private String password;
    private Date dob;

    @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER, cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="user_id")
    private Set<Role> roles = new HashSet<>();
    ...  
}
```

UserRepository.java

```
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Serializable>{
}
```

UserService.java

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class UserService 
{

@Autowired
private UserRepository userRepository;

public List<User> findAll() {
    return userRepository.findAll();
}

public User create(User user) {
    return userRepository.save(user);
}
```

UserServiceTest.java

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(loader=AnnotationConfigContextLoader.class)
public class UserServiceTest {

 @Configuration
 static class ContextConfiguration {

     @Bean
     public UserService userService() {
        UserService userService = new UserService();
        return userService;
    }
 }

@Autowired
private UserService userService;

private User user;

@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    user = new User(1, "victor", "victort@asd.ad", "sfd", null);
}

@Test
public void testCreate() {
    User result = userService.create(user);
    user = result;
}
```

}

The error:

```
root@pupim:~/workspace/tcc-gestao-residuos# mvn tomcat7:run-war -DskipTests
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building TCC Gestão de Resíduos UEM 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] >>> tomcat7-maven-plugin:2.2:run-war (default-cli) @ tcc-gestao-residuos >>>
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.3:resources (default-resources) @ tcc-gestao-residuos ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ tcc-gestao-residuos ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.3:testResources (default-testResources) @ tcc-gestao-residuos ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ tcc-gestao-residuos ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.10:test (default-test) @ tcc-gestao-residuos ---
[INFO] Tests are skipped.
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-war-plugin:2.1.1:war (default-war) @ tcc-gestao-residuos ---
[INFO] Packaging webapp
[INFO] Assembling webapp [tcc-gestao-residuos] in [/root/workspace/tcc-gestao-residuos/target/tcc-gestao-residuos]
[INFO] Processing war project
[INFO] Copying webapp resources [/root/workspace/tcc-gestao-residuos/src/main/webapp]
[INFO] Webapp assembled in [319 msecs]
[INFO] Building war: /root/workspace/tcc-gestao-residuos/target/tcc-gestao-residuos.war
[INFO] WEB-INF/web.xml already added, skipping
[INFO] 
[INFO] <<< tomcat7-maven-plugin:2.2:run-war (default-cli) @ tcc-gestao-residuos <<<
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- tomcat7-maven-plugin:2.2:run-war (default-cli) @ tcc-gestao-residuos ---
[INFO] Running war on http://localhost:8080/tcc-gestao-residuos
[INFO] Creating Tomcat server configuration at /root/workspace/tcc-gestao-residuos/target/tomcat
[INFO] create webapp with contextPath: /tcc-gestao-residuos
ago 10, 2015 5:47:37 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFORMAÇÕES: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
ago 10, 2015 5:47:37 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFORMAÇÕES: Starting service Tomcat
ago 10, 2015 5:47:37 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFORMAÇÕES: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.47
ago 10, 2015 5:47:37 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader validateJarFile
INFORMAÇÕES: validateJarFile(/root/workspace/tcc-gestao-residuos/target/tcc-gestao-residuos/WEB-INF/lib/javax.servlet-api-3.0.1.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 2.3, section 9.7.2. Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class
ago 10, 2015 5:47:41 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFORMAÇÕES: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/core_rt is already defined
ago 10, 2015 5:47:41 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFORMAÇÕES: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/core is already defined
ago 10, 2015 5:47:41 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFORMAÇÕES: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core is already defined
ago 10, 2015 5:47:41 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFORMAÇÕES: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/fmt_rt is already defined
ago 10, 2015 5:47:41 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFORMAÇÕES: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/fmt is already defined
ago 10, 2015 5:47:41 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFORMAÇÕES: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt is already defined
ago 10, 2015 5:47:41 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFORMAÇÕES: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions is already defined
ago 10, 2015 5:47:41 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFORMAÇÕES: TLD skipped. URI: http://jakarta.apache.org/taglibs/standard/permittedTaglibs is already defined
ago 10, 2015 5:47:41 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFORMAÇÕES: TLD skipped. URI: http://jakarta.apache.org/taglibs/standard/scriptfree is already defined
ago 10, 2015 5:47:41 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFORMAÇÕES: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/sql_rt is already defined
ago 10, 2015 5:47:41 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFORMAÇÕES: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/sql is already defined
ago 10, 2015 5:47:41 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
... 'org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.enhancedConfigurationProcessor'
17:47:42.297 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.context.event.internalEventListenerFactory'
17:47:42.329 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.s.w.c.s.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext - Unable to locate LifecycleProcessor with name 'lifecycleProcessor': using default [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor@6316386e]
17:47:42.331 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'lifecycleProcessor'
17:47:42.335 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.s.c.e.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver - Searching for key 'spring.liveBeansView.mbeanDomain' in [servletConfigInitParams]
17:47:42.336 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.s.c.e.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver - Searching for key 'spring.liveBeansView.mbeanDomain' in [servletContextInitParams]
17:47:42.336 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.s.c.e.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver - Searching for key 'spring.liveBeansView.mbeanDomain' in [jndiProperties]
17:47:42.336 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate - Looking up JNDI object with name [java:comp/env/spring.liveBeansView.mbeanDomain]
17:47:42.336 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.s.jndi.JndiLocatorDelegate - Converted JNDI name [java:comp/env/spring.liveBeansView.mbeanDomain] not found - trying original name [spring.liveBeansView.mbeanDomain]. javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [spring.liveBeansView.mbeanDomain] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [spring.liveBeansView.mbeanDomain].
17:47:42.337 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate - Looking up JNDI object with name [spring.liveBeansView.mbeanDomain]
17:47:42.338 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.s.jndi.JndiPropertySource - JNDI lookup for name [spring.liveBeansView.mbeanDomain] threw NamingException with message: Name [spring.liveBeansView.mbeanDomain] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [spring.liveBeansView.mbeanDomain].. Returning null.
17:47:42.338 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.s.c.e.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver - Searching for key 'spring.liveBeansView.mbeanDomain' in [systemProperties]
17:47:42.338 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.s.c.e.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver - Searching for key 'spring.liveBeansView.mbeanDomain' in [systemEnvironment]
17:47:42.338 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.s.c.e.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver - Could not find key 'spring.liveBeansView.mbeanDomain' in any property source. Returning [null]
17:47:42.340 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.s.web.context.ContextLoader - Published root WebApplicationContext as ServletContext attribute with name [org.springframework.web.context.WebApplicationContext.ROOT]
17:47:42.349 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  o.s.web.context.ContextLoader - Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 377 ms
17:47:42.371 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.s.o.j.s.OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter - Initializing filter 'openEntityManagerInViewFilter'
17:47:42.374 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.s.o.j.s.OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter - Filter 'openEntityManagerInViewFilter' configured successfully
17:47:42.376 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.s.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy - Initializing filter 'delegatingFilterProxy'
ago 10, 2015 5:47:42 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext filterStart
GRAVE: Exception starting filter delegatingFilterProxy
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'springSecurityFilterChain' is defined
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanDefinition(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:698)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getMergedLocalBeanDefinition(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1174)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:283)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:201)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1051)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.initDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:326)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.initFilterBean(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:235)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.GenericFilterBean.init(GenericFilterBean.java:199)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.initFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:281)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:111)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4775)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5452)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

ago 10, 2015 5:47:42 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
GRAVE: Error filterStart
ago 10, 2015 5:47:42 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
GRAVE: Context [/tcc-gestao-residuos] startup failed due to previous errors
ago 10, 2015 5:47:42 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFORMAÇÕES: Closing Spring root WebApplicationContext
17:47:42.393 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  o.s.w.c.s.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext - Closing Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Mon Aug 10 17:47:41 BRT 2015]; root of context hierarchy
17:47:42.394 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'lifecycleProcessor'
17:47:42.394 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Destroying singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@f8fe9ce: defining beans [org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalPersistenceAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.event.internalEventListenerProcessor,org.springframework.context.event.internalEventListenerFactory,org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.importAwareProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.enhancedConfigurationProcessor]; root of factory hierarchy
ago 10, 2015 5:47:42 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesJdbc
GRAVE: The web application [/tcc-gestao-residuos] registered the JDBC driver [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver] but failed to unregister it when the web application was stopped. To prevent a memory leak, the JDBC Driver has been forcibly unregistered.
ago 10, 2015 5:47:42 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads
GRAVE: The web application [/tcc-gestao-residuos] appears to have started a thread named [Abandoned connection cleanup thread] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
ago 10, 2015 5:47:42 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFORMAÇÕES: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
```

...

could somebody help me?... is this the right config? what is missing?!?!
I tried a lot of solutions found here and other sites, but all failed

Sorry the mess... it's my first post

thanks a lot

Comment: Post the whole stack trace, especially the part where it probably tells you what bean is missing.

Comment: edit - Insert the stack trace

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that you have a `web.xml` file in your project which is referencing the `springSecurityFilterChain` filter via Spring `DelegatingFilterProxy`

You should either remove it from your web.xml for your unit tests, or add it to your test spring context